# how to get the AzureActiveDirectory authentication settings of azure web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I recently published a website to azure and it works fine. After publishing I configured authentication for it by going to manage.windowsazure.com . And now it gets redirected to corp.sts authentication.

Now if I want to test the same from my local host , I think I need to get all those settings added in web.config or I should modify my local web.config in the source code.

But is that possible to get the web.config settings from the published website since it might have been updated with Authentication ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change things in both the Azure AD entry (you need to add localhost as a new return URL) and in your app (you need to specify localhost as a reply URL).You can find instructions for those two tasks by leafing through the readme of https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet